# Custom Post Type permalink doesn't match post permalink

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks

I created a Custom Post Type for Games, but when I add it, the permalink is showing as http://site.com?my_games=test-game where my_games is the custom post type name and test-game is the post name.

I have `'rewrite' => false,`, is there something else I should be doing?

I want the permalink structure to be the same as regular posts, `/%category%/%postname%/`

What do I need to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question has the answer right in it!

> I have 'rewrite' => false,, is there something else I should be doing?

[From the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Arguments):

> To prevent rewrites, set to false.

By setting that to false, you're preventing the default behavior that you want.

Comment: oh, I thought setting to false would prevent the post type from doing a rewrite of it's own. Changed it to an array with a slug specified and that seems to do the trick. thanks